# Join column of same type but different length on 2 tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-indexes

I have 2 tables with each having a column sub_id of type nvarchar2 but different length (one is 30 another is 255 in length). I have db indexes created on both of these tables on their respective sub_id columns. I am taking a join on these tables on sub_id column.

My tables have millions of rows thus a join without index use takes a lot of time. I am not sure if the indexes are being used here as I suspect the difference in column length could cause a full table scan.

Please provide with insight as I am fairly new to such basic db admin concepts. 
   I have tried to read up more on this but could find anything specific enough.

EDIT: 
Another query, can we have these 2 sub_id columns as one being varchar2 and another as nvarchar and have indexes used as well ?

Comment: Look at the explain plan to see if the indexes are being used.  However, if these are keys between two tables, you should define a proper `foreign key` relationship and fix the types so they are the same length.

Comment: Oracle will use the index - provided the index usage makes sense. Indexes are not a magic "make everything go faster" tool.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if you could point me to some literature that describes when it makes sense to use indexes and when not, would be grateful. From what I know, index usage should speed up the queries I am using but I am skeptical if indexes will come in play given the differences in column types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the data types are compatible - i.e. no (implicit) conversions needed - the optimizer can use an index to join the tables.

> My tables have millions of rows thus a join without index use takes a
>   lot of time

That depends!

If you're fetching most* of the rows from both tables, it can be faster to full scan both. Then hash join the results.

For example, this joins all the rows from both tables. You're getting everything, so there's no need to use an index:

```
create table t1 (
  c1, c2
) as
  select cast ( level as nvarchar2(30) ) , rpad ( 'stuff', 100, 'f' )
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 1000;

create table t2 (
  c1, c2, c3
) as
  select cast ( level as nvarchar2(255) ) , mod ( level, 333 ) , rpad ( 'stuff', 100, 'f' ) 
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 1000;

create index i1
  on t1 ( c1 );

create index i2
  on t2 ( c1 );

create index i2_c2
  on t2 ( c2 );  

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( user, 't1' ) ;
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats ( user, 't2' ) ;

set serveroutput off
alter session set statistics_level = all;

select * from t1
join   t2
on     t1.c1 = t2.c1;

select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'IOSTATS LAST'));

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |      1 |        |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |      45 |    
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN         |      |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |      45 |    
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |      18 |    
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2   |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |      27 |    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What if you're getting few* rows from one table?

You'll want to use an index to find them. And - provided each of these links to just a handful of rows in the other table - use an index on the second table in a nested loops join. As shown in this example which gets three rows from one table. Each of which join to one in the other:

```
select * from t1
join   t2
on     t1.c1 = t2.c1
where  t2.c2 = 0;

select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'IOSTATS LAST'));

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
| Id  | Operation                     | Name  | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |       |      1 |        |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |    
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                 |       |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      13 |    
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |       |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      10 |    
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T2    |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |       5 |    
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I2_C2 |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |    
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN           | I1    |      3 |      1 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |       5 |    
|   6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | T1    |      3 |      1 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note this does rely on the join columns both being `nvarchar2` or `varchar2`. These are *incompatible* types. So if you mix and match these, the optimizer will be unable to use an index on the join columns.

Switching t1.c1 from `nvarchar2` -> `varchar2` in the previous examples shows this. Now, despite getting few rows from both tables, the optimizer full scans `t3`:

```
create table t3 as 
  select cast ( c1 as varchar2(30) ) c1, c2 from t1;

select * from t3
join   t2
on     t3.c1 = t2.c1
where  t2.c2 = 0;

select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null, null, 'IOSTATS LAST'));

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
| Id  | Operation                    | Name  | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |       |      1 |        |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      24 |    
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                   |       |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |      24 |    
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T2    |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |       5 |    
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I2_C2 |      1 |      3 |      3 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |    
|   4 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | T3    |      1 |   1000 |   1000 |00:00:00.01 |      19 |    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                 
---------------------------------------------------                                                 

   1 - access("T2"."C1"=SYS_OP_C2C("T3"."C1"))                                                      
   3 - access("T2"."C2"=0)
```

Notice the `SYS_OP_C2C` operation on `t3.c1`? This is a function. Which means the database can't use the (non-function-based) index on this column. So you have a full scan.

Note* Few and most are relative terms! There are no absolute values for these. I discuss this further in [this video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL78V83xV2fYlLA-bjMU2ZvUKQOZNrqLEa).

Comment: Brilliant answer! Cheers!